Can't remove bleed screw SRAM shifter
I'm trying to bleed my SRAM Force D2 brakes, but I can't remove the bleed screw underneath the shifter cover:

When I try to remove the torx screw, the round part underneath (with the 111... numbers) also turns freely (although with some resistance).
Any idea how to fix this issue?

FWIW: took it to the LBS, they labelled it as "broken", and ordered a new one under warranty.
